# Power out to only one room

Tags: electrical

There is only power out to this room, light off and electrical sockets not working, no tripped breakers and no gfci outlet (sorry if I spelled gfci wrong) we've tried everything we know

Comment: Do you know which breaker is **supposed** to control this room? There is some basic trouble-shooting you can do, but (a) you need the right tools to be safe and (b) you **must** be sure you have the correct breaker turned off before doing anything.

Comment: Did you check for damage done by animals?  I had a raccoon chew through wires before.  Thankfully it was scared off before it electrocuted itself and died in the wall.  Didn't lose power but did find considerable damage to wires.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to suspect GFCI outlets.  Generally a GFCI outlet turns off the single GFCI outlet; but, when the outlet is wired to other outlets, the first GFCI to trip will turn off all the other outlets.  Often people think the outlets on a circuit are organized by room; but, often they are not.  Search for GFCI outlets in adjoining rooms or places between your box and the room that is dark.  You might find a tripped GFCI that you didn't know was protecting the dark room in another room.

You are right to suspect your circuit breakers in your circuit breaker box.  Normally a breaker trips and throws itself out of its normal position into the off position.  Sometimes a breaker will trip, but the position of the breaker doesn't change.  Attempt to identify the breaker to that room, and purposefully shut it off an turn it on again.  If you are not sure which breaker controls the room, purposefully turn off all the breakers that could be controlling the room and turn them on.

At this point, you need to consider if you know enough about electricity to continue; and, before you say "yes" consider that it's not what you know that will harm you, it is what you don't know.  Many people injure themselves, kill themselves, or start fires because they "didn't know" how to protect against a situation they never considered could happen.

The rest of the failure scenarios:

- A device on the circuit (outlet, switch, etc.) failed, taking down all downstream items with it (common).
- The circuit breaker failed (rare, but possible).
- The wiring failed (rare, but possible).
- The wiring was mis-wired (more frequent than it should be, often not detected until another failure exposes the problem).

The main problem is that, without more information it is impossible to know which combination the above occurred.  Multiple failures are more common than they seem; so it is not safe to assume a single failure.  The right combinations of these failures can even energize disconnected circuits.

If you are sure you've reset everything, even the stuff that didn't need resetting; odds are you are dangerously close to considering working on the wires behind the plate.  My recommendation to the average person is "Don't do it."  Unless you have a history of successfully accomplishing smaller electrical projects, working on powered lines, and debugging electrical failures, this one is bigger and potentially more dangerous than you are likely imagining.

Answer (score 0):

Most common problem is a wire has come loose feeding in or out of a daisy chained a stab back receptacle.

Each device that is not working will need to be removed tod verify the wires are firmly held in place and replace any device that the wires have come loose. Really best practice is to replace any stab back device that you tamper with, use screw terminals with solid wire, and make short pigtail connections to connect the replacement devices rather than using the device as a splice point.

Start with devices closest to your panel. If none of the failed devices restores power then the working devices on opposite sides of the walls and adjacent to the failed ones will need to be checked to see if the hot connection feeding out of the device has come loose.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any 220V heating appliances such as an electric dryer or oven turn one on and see if it heats at that point check the room light and plugs. If still out and the appliances heat that eliminates a bad incoming phase. Try cycling all of your breakers one may have tripped and not be visible. Interesting that the room light also failed, that should be a seperate circuit. My best would be a bad stab connection on a duplex failed. You will have to check them one by one. Sometimes banging them with your hand can cause a flicker. Otherwise for a starting point select the one that is closest to your breaker panel. If so replace the outlet with one that uses screws. The more stab receptacle you replace the better and a side effect is it will reduce noise in your AM radio. Hint replace each stab receptacle as you check it. Then turn on the breaker to validate it fixed it. These stab terminals can fail without the wire coming out of the hole.